# How do I make table border black on bootstrap for print

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-print

I want to print my page where there's table in it. When i print it it always change to bootstrap default color. I'm using ctrl+p / cmd+p for printing. I'm using bootstrap 4 and laravel 5.7

i've tried to use `!important;` still not working

My CSS

```
<style media="screen">
@media print{
  .table thead tr td,.table tbody tr td {
     border: 1px solid #000000!important;
  }
}
</style>
```

My Table

```
<table class="col-12 table table-bordered table-sm" >
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price (IDR)</th>
        <th>Amount (IDR)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    @php
      $total=0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($ra->sale->details as $items)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $items->good->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $items->qty }} pcs</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($items->units,0,',','.') }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($items->total,0,',','.') }}</td>
      </tr>
      @php
        $total += $items->total;
      @endphp
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<style media="print">
  .table thead tbody tfoot tr td {
     border: 1px solid #000000!important;
  }
</style>`

EDIT 2: (Add .thead-light selector)

```
<style media="print">
  .thead-light {
     border: 1px solid #000000!important;
  }
</style>
```

might be able to remove !important if your selector is specific enough:

```
.table .thead-light {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

or

```
.table .thead-light tbody tfoot tr td {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: it worked but i have thead with class `thead-light` and it's not affected

Comment: add another style targetting thead-light then. That class is not selected here

Comment: i'm using this but it has no effect `.table thead thead-light tr td{
      border: 1px solid #000000 !important;
    }`

Comment: Srry that would select it if it was nested like that, just do one only for .thead-light

Comment: Or try .*table.thead-light* thead tr td {...}

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. This will overwrite the default css.

```
@media print{
            .table thead tr td,.table tbody tr td{
                border-width: 1px !important;
                border-style: solid !important;
                border-color: #000 !important;
            }
        }
```

Comment: it has no effect somehow but stefan's answer worked thanks btw

Comment: This solution might work using .table thead tr *th*  - one does not use td in thead tr

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your style tag:** this is useful for tables which is having `<thead>` tags as well.

```
@media print{
        .table thead tr td,.table tbody tr td{
            border-width: 1px !important;
            border-style: solid !important;
            border-color: black !important;

            -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact ;
        }


        .ta thead tr td,.ta tbody tr td{

            border-width: 0.7px !important;
            border-style: solid !important;
            border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.644) !important;

            -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact ;
        }
    }
```

---

If it stills won't work, try it inline:

```
<table style="  border-width: 1px !important;
                border-style: solid !important;
                border-color: black !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact ;
             ">
</table>
```